# Run Power shell exe and perform certain steps in that exe

Tags: powershell, start-process

I have an .exe file that I'm running using Start-Process. Once this exe is launched, I want to perform certain steps like click on the 'Next' button or some other button on that exe. How can I perform these actions on a exe through shell script?

```
Start-Process -FilePath $MyExe -WorkingDirectory $MyPath
```

Comment: What is the use case? If it's an installer there's usually command line options for automated installation.

Comment: This one doesn't have any command line option

Comment: Then you should yell at whomever is selling it to you. While you wait for them you could always try this: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/find-hidden-command-line-silent-switches-for-setup-files/